# why does my elderflower wine take so much longer than elderberry wine?

Tags: fermentation

I have similar recipes for elderflower and elderberry wine, using six kilos of sugar to 23 litres of water. Both have the same additives, yeast, acid mix and nutrient - the elderberry is ready to kill at about 3 weeks, but the elderflower takes about six weeks.  Both are the same temperature,  I use about 2 ounces of dried flowers and 500g of dried berries.

Answer (score 2):

The elderberry wine has a good deal more nutrients in it, since it uses the whole berries. You won't get a lot of nutrients from the elderflowers themselves.

Yeast are more than just a way to turn sugar into alcohol and CO2 - they have complex nutritional needs at different stages of their growth. Generally whole fruit can provide everything they need - but the closer you get to simple sugar water, the more the yeast will struggle to perform the chemical reactions needed at different stages of their lifecycle.